# Фиксированные заголовки в Grid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-grid

Как можно зафиксировать верхний хедер от скроллинга по-вертикали и боковой от скролла по-горизонтали? 
Компонент `Grid`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Верхний и так не должен скроллится (если конечно вы свой DataGrid в [ScrollViewer](http://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CC0QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fru-ru%2Flibrary%2Fsystem.windows.controls.scrollviewer(v%3Dvs.110).aspx&ei=mFSxUunuGqbZ4QTF5IGQCQ&usg=AFQjCNHBrgHI57xxdJn_sqjLYBbreY6Pug&sig2=ha8kZg1rNWn5fqwZGXovrQ&bvm=bv.58187178,d.bGE) не обернули), а вот боковые (левые) можно зафиксировать с помощью свойства [FrozenColumnCount](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.frozencolumncount(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
<DataGrid FrozenColumnCount="2"/> <!--Зафиксировали первых два столбца-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Никак (через стандартный GridView), только путем неэстетических с точки зрения юзера трюков...

Comment: @en2012, не подскажите такие трюки или компонент, который бы решил данную задачу?)

Comment: ну, например, вот статейка:
http://www.dotnetbull.com/2011/11/scrollable-gridview-with-fixed-headers.html
а можно и так:
http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/JQuery-Scrollable-GridView-with-Fixed-Header-in-ASPNet.aspx

Comment: @en2012, не ASP..

Comment: тогда все нормуль, ответ ниже